# HTML form not submitting correctly using PHP

Tags: php, apache2, windows-server-2008-r2

For 6-7 hours I've been burning my head with this problem but couldn't find the issue nor the solution.

I've been working on a multi-step registration form on my server and i have to move it to a dedicated windows server with php 5.2.17 and apache 2.2.
The problem is that in this new environment it is not working as expected. The logic of my script is the following(and this is the order in my file):

1. Create my 3 form objects (with method=post and action=the same file)
2. Validate each form and if true put the entered data in a session and then do a `header("location: {$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=the_next_step");`
3. Start displaying the page and depending on the `$_REQUEST['page']`, rendering the neccessary form object (if there's no value for page render form 1, if value for page=2 render form 2 and so on).

In IE for example; when I fill in the first form and submit it, it won't even get to the validation if statement.

In firefox I can go through the steps but in the address bar I can't see my query strings(page=2, page=3).

Any idea what could be the problem?
Is there any setting which must be done on php/apache on the server? Is there an issue with GET or POST or submitting data?
And also I see a very weird thing: the source code of my page is being rendered in `<framesets>`.

Running PHP 5.2.17 + Apache 2.2 Windows 2008 server

Ok, so after some more research i found out that i may have something to do with sessions. 
I see that in IE session is not working and is being destroyed.
This is the code:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if (!isset($fv)) $fv = &$_SESSION['rgform']['page1'];
    if (!isset($fv1)) $fv1 = &$_SESSION['rgform']['page2'];
    if (!isset($fv2)) $fv2 = &$_SESSION['rgform']['page3'];
```

Now I'm creating my objects

```
if ($form->validate()) 
{
    $_SESSION['rgform']['page1'] = $_POST;
   header("location: {$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=step2");
}

if ($form2->validate()) 
{
   $_SESSION['rgform']['page2'] = $_POST;
   header("location: {$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=step3"); 
}

if ($form3->validate()) 
{
   $_SESSION['rgform']['page3'] = $_POST;
   header("location: {$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=step4");
}

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<!-- load my css, js etc -->
<body>
if(!isset($_REQUEST['page']) )
{
    $form->render('custom-template.php');

}
elseif( $_REQUEST['page']== "step2" && $_SESSION['rgform']['page1']['pagename']== "part_det" ) // on each form i have an hidden input with the name "pagename" and different value
{
    $form2->render('custom-template-2.php');
}
elseif($_REQUEST['page']== "step3" && $_SESSION['rgform']['page2']['pagename']=="comp_det")
{
    $form3->render('custom-template-3.php');
}
elseif($_REQUEST['page']== "step4" && $_SESSION['rgform']['page3']['pagename']== "buss_det")
{
    echo "Thanks!!";
    session_destroy();
}
</body>
</html>
```

Now, as i told you i'm printing my session on the page and when i click on submit all the POST data should be written in the session but somehow that is not working on IE and that's why i can go and render form 2.

Another interesting thing is that i'm not able to see the query string in the address bar of my browser even if after form 1 is validated i do: `header("location: {$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=step2");`
Is this a server setup issue?

Comment: Can you please add some code so we can see what you've got now.  Also putting in the HTML that is being rendered would be helpful

Comment: i think you're using short open tags **<?** but you didn't turned it on in the php.ini

Comment: If you can't work it out looking at the code, how are we supposed to without seeing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.
It seems that the DNS provider has a "cloaking" feature which is displaying the content in a frame so IE security wasn't saving session variables from a frame.

Comment: As soon as you are able, be sure and mark this answer as accepted so others will know that there is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly a session problem. A session ID (the element that identifies your users for the server), can be stored on the client on one of 2 ways:

1. It could be a cookie, in which case you need to make sure the client has cookies enabled and that he does not erase them in the middle of the action.
2. It could be as a GET variable, in which case you need to make sure the session ID remains in the GET `mysite.com/index.php?page=step1&sid=03c7c0ace395d80182db07ae2c30f034` (`sid` is an example for a session ID that must be retained).

If you fail to save the session ID, the session would die and the server won't remember (or identify) your users correctly.

Comment: I see but the are two more things i don't understand: on firefox the session is being saved with my POST data and then header(location) redirects me to page=2. Why isn't this working in IE? Are the session settings on the windows server wrong? And my big question mark is the fact that on my shared server(which is on linux) this script is working perfectly.